# Authenticated user is null in laravel middleware

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to prevent some users from accessing admin panel.
I have created a middleware with this code called RequireAdminRole

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    dd($user);

    if (!$user) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    if (!$user->hasRole('Admin')) {
        // if your sessions are decoupled from the frontend
        // you can even logout the user like so:
        // auth()->logout();

        abort(403, 'Access denied');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

I have added it to kernel.php

```
'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\RequireAdminRole::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
```

My problem id $user has null value, so I can't get user permissions.
Can anybody help me?

Best regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order of your middleware is important, the middleware handlers are executed in the order that they are defined. This means that you are trying to retrieve the authenticated user from the session before the `StartSession` middleware has been executed.

So to solve your issue, you should move your `RequireAdminRole` middleware to the end of the array, or at least after the definition of `StartSession`.

```
'web' => [
    // Other middleware definitions...
    \App\Http\Middleware\RequireAdminRole::class
],
```